# How to make Python Azure Function (v2) Block Requests without functionkey/code

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have created my first Python Azure Function (v2) and detected that the function accepts all requests regardless if they have the "code"(FunctionKey) param used in .Net Azure functions.

How can I make the function block all requests that don't have a valid key attached?

Comment: Can you update your question with function.json file?

Comment: I suspect that you have set `authLevel` to `anonymous` in function.json

Comment: Hi, I don't have a function.json file

Comment: What is your folder structre?

Comment: is the azure function python v2 folder structure you can see here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/416002iCE1AB9B5F71CA1CD/image-size/large?v=v2&px=999

Comment: Abdul I reread you reply I indeed have the function set to anonymous. but it is not in the function.json

Comment: app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

searching a bit more about it

Comment: Got the data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.authorizationlevel?view=azure-java-stable  I had it set to anonymous, which doesn't require a Key. I should set it to either Admin or Function. Thanks for the Help

Comment: If you want to create an answer go ahead and I'll accept it else I'll answer myself

Comment: It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Comment: hi @NaveenSharma I coincidentally just did that, hope it helps. cheers (Consider upvoting it if you like it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was changing the authlevel from anonymous to Function (you can change to Admin too). then you just have to invoke the function with the functionKey (code) in all your requests. Thanks Abdul for the help.

```
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
```

[More info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python)